# How to split an Integer into an Array using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I apologise if this has already been asked before, but I was unable to find a conclusive answer after some extensive searching, so I thought I would ask here. I am a beginner to Java (to coding, in general) and was tasked with writing a program that takes a user-inputted 3 digit number, and adds those three digits.

Note: I cannot use loops for this task, and the three digits must all be inputted at once.

```
String myInput;
    myInput =        
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Hello, and welcome to the ThreeDigit program. "
    + "\nPlease input a three digit number below. \nThreeDigit will add those three numbers and     display their sum.");
    int threedigitinput;
    threedigitinput = Integer.parseInt(myInput);
```

Comment: Why do you want to create an array? Why not just pull each digit out of the input string and add them? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways, one of which would be...

```
    String ss[] = "123".split("");
    int i = 
            Integer.parseInt(ss[0]) + 
            Integer.parseInt(ss[1]) + 
            Integer.parseInt(ss[2]);
    System.out.println(i);
```

another would be...

```
    String s = "123";
    int i = 
            Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)) +
            Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(1)) +
            Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(2));
    System.out.println(i);
```

and still another would be...

```
    String s = "123";
    int i = 
            s.charAt(0) +
            s.charAt(1) +
            s.charAt(2) - 
            (3 * 48);
    System.out.println(i);
```

BUT hard coding for 3 numbers isn't very useful beyond this simple case. So how about recursion??

```
public static int addDigis(String s) {
        if(s.length() == 1)
            return s.charAt(0) - 48;
        return s.charAt(0) - 48 + addDigis(s.substring(1, s.length()));
}
```

> Output for each example: 6

Answer (score 0):

you can use integer math to come up with the three numbers seperately

```
int first = threedigitinput / 100;
int second = (threedigitinput % 100) / 10;
int third = threedigitinput % 10;
```

Comment: an overkill, given that he can simply extract the digits and add them.

Comment: i know but this is the first thing that came to my mind with what the question already had done

Answer (score 0):

Classic example of using `divmod`:

```
public class SumIntegerDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumOfDigitsSimple(248));    // 14
        System.out.println(sumOfDigitsIterative(248)); // 14
        System.out.println(sumOfDigitsRecursive(248)); // 14
    }

    // Simple, non-loop solution
    public static final int sumOfDigitsSimple(int x) {
        int y = x % 1000; // Make sure that the value has no more than 3 digits.
        return divmod(y,100)[0]+divmod(divmod(y,100)[1],10)[0]+divmod(y,10)[1];
    }

    // Iterative Solution
    public static final int sumOfDigitsIterative(int x) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (x > 0) {
            int[] y = divmod(x, 10);
            sum += y[1];
            x = y[0];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    // Tail-recursive Solution
    public static final int sumOfDigitsRecursive(int x) {
        if (x <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int[] y = divmod(x, 10);
        return sumOfDigitsRecursive(y[0]) + y[1];
    }

    public static final int[] divmod(final int x, int m) {
        return new int[] { (x / m), (x % m) };
    }
}
```

Comment: no loops as he said. simple string parsing and adding should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use [`Character.digit(char,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) to get the value for each character with something like -

```
int value = Character.digit(myInput.charAt(0), 10)
        + Character.digit(myInput.charAt(1), 10)
        + Character.digit(myInput.charAt(2), 10);
```