# Storing digits of numbers in array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello fellow programmers !
I am a beginner with Java and i am looking for a method or a way maybe to store the digits of a 6 digit number entered by the user , in an int array.
For example :-
if the number is 675421.
then i want to store the digits in an array like :-

```
int[] array = new int[6];
int number = 675421 
array[0] = 6;
array[1] = 7;
array[2] = 5; 
array[3] = 4;
array[4] = 2;
array[5] = 1;
```

I want to do so so that i can work with the array to maybe sort or change the order or numbers in array. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split an Integer into an Array using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319579/how-to-split-an-integer-into-an-array-using-java)

Comment: @Mr.Momo what is your question?

Comment: Oh im really sorry if it is a duplicate....its just that i didnt quite understand what to do in this case . so if anyone can explain to me the thing to be done and the logic behind it ?

Comment: My question is how to reproduce such an array from a given number or a number entered by the user. I want to separately store the digits in a array

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8033593/4272498

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
String temp = Integer.toString(number);

int[] num = new int[temp.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
    num[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
}

for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

**Edit, after comment**

Here, First, you are converting to your `number` to a string.
Then, take each char out of it(in the loop), subtract the `ASCII` value of `0` from each char to get the digit [ie, `ASCII` of `0` is `48`, `1` is `49`, ... ] (see [`ASCII` table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html))

Comment: Thanks ! can u explain me the line within the first for loop?

Comment: Answer Updated, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
String number = "123123";
    int[] intArray = new int[number.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++)
    {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(number.charAt(i)));
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the recursive solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int testNum = 675421;
    List<Integer> digitList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    collectDigits(testNum, digitList);
    Object[] resultArr = digitList.toArray();
    int listSize = resultArr.length;
    for (int listCount = 0; listCount < listSize; listCount++) {
        System.out.println("result["+listCount+"] = "+resultArr[listCount]);
    }
}

private static void collectDigits(int num, List<Integer> digits) {
    if (num / 10 > 0) {
        collectDigits(num / 10, digits);
    }
    digits.add(num % 10);
}
```

Comment: A bit complicated for me but thanks anyways. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I have divided the number by 10, store the remainder in an array, call collectDigits function with quotient as the new number

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to turn the original integer into a string.
Loop over the string, parsing each character back to an int, and place into the array. Here is an example:

```
int number = 123456;

String strNumber = number+"";

int[] array = new int[strNumber.length()];

int index = 0;

for(char c : strNumber.toCharArray()){
    array[index++] = Integer.parseInt(c+"");
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Math solution, you can split the int number using this:

```
int[] array = new int[6];
int number = 675421;
array[0] = ((number/100000)%10);
array[1] = ((number/10000)%10);
array[2] = ((number/1000)%10);
array[3] = ((number/100)%10);
array[4] = ((number/10)%10);
array[5] = ((number/1)%10);
```

If the "number" has a variable length you can automate this, write a coment if you need help